# Chrome - need scroll to appended item

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll, append

I have a pagination button (Show More). This button append extra products in the bottom of existed product list, as everywhere. So, then I click on this button in Firefox, new products will apear in front of me, as I need. So, I should scroll down to see (Show More) button again, it's absolutely okey.

But, the same action in Chrome stuck windows in front of (Show More) button. And this is a problem. If I wanna see new products, I should scroll up to check new products and then AGAIN scroll down to see (Show More) button again.

Could you help me? How can i fix this problem in Chrome?

I'm using jquery function append:

```
$('#product-list').append(response);
```

Comment: I found a solution, not sure that it's a good one, but it's all I have at this time.

replace: 

`$('#product-list').append(response);` 

with: 

`var dataScroll = $('#load-format-pagination').offset().top + $('#load-format-pagination').height();`

`$('#product-list').append(response);`

`$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: dataScroll }, 500);
`

Comment: Please, let me know, if there is a better way to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Save position before appending and after append scroll to this position.

```
let scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

// append

$(document).scrollTop(scrollPosition);
```